# iOS app User simulation and monitoring?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to develop a new app or code to simulate user interface in another already existing app and get textFields, messages, etc results. Something like KIF (https://github.com/square/KIF), but I would like it to be independently compiled (not embedded in the same project).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have App A to be able to interact with the UI of App B.

This is not possible.

Comment: I understand this is not recommended by apple, but my app or code will not be going in the app store. It is just for monitoring and surveillance purposes, and can use private APIs (as long as they work). Do you think it is also not possible with the use of private APIs?

Comment: Apps are sandboxed so you can't access outside of that sandbox. Also, you can only have one app running at a time so communication between the apps is not possible as there is only one active at a time. Perhaps if you jailbreak the device then you might be able to, but as it is, you can't.

Comment: It is possible to have one active app and another background app. If somehow I could get the background app to get a pointer to the [UIApplication sharedApplication] object of the active app, it would be great. Jailbreaking, private APIs, it is all an option.

Comment: A "Background" app isn't running. It just saves the state so it can switch back again quickly to give the impression it was still running. Only certain things can really be done in the background (data transfer, voip and playing music)

Comment: I'm able to get the list of my UIViews from the background and send them through NSLog messages. (while the other app is active) The only problem is that they are the UIViews in the first app, and not in the second. I need the pointer of the second app to get those.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Comments are not for extended conversations. If you have more questions, post them as individual questions.